# Flex Mobile Project, insert multiple Image object in array

Tags: arrays, image, apache-flex, flex-mobile

I have indexed Image, like these:

```
<s:Image id="imgListaTaskAnalysis0" left="20" top="110" width="200" height="200"/>
<s:Image id="imgListaTaskAnalysis1" left="20" top="360" width="200" height="200"/>
<s:Image id="imgListaTaskAnalysis2" left="20" top="360" width="200" height="200"/>
```

And so on..

I want to put them in an array, so:

```
public var arrayImg:Array = new Array(imgListaTaskAnalysis0,imgListaTaskAnalysis1,imgListaTaskAnalysis2);
```

But I can't give them a source:

```
for(var i:Number=0;i<=arrayImg.length;i++)
                arrayImg[i].source = cuboImmagini.path;
```

In this way doesn't work, doesn't give them any source..There is a way to do this?

It is the interested part of my project:

```
public var arrayImg:Array = new Array(imgListaTaskAnalysis0,imgListaTaskAnalysis1);
/*          DICHIARAZIONE IMMAGINI          */
public var cuboImmagini:Object = {path:"../assets/cuboImmagini.png"};
public var exit:Object = {path:"../assets/exit.png"};
public var home:Object = {path:"../assets/home.png"};
/*          FINE DICHIARAZIONE IMMAGINI     */

/*          FUNZIONI            */

//  cambiaPagina
public function cambiaPagina(prossimaPagina:String):void
{   
currentState = prossimaPagina;
}

// chiudiApplicazione
protected function chiudiApplicazione(event:MouseEvent):void    
{
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}
public function carica():void
        {
            arrayImg[0].source = cuboImmagini.path;
            arrayImg[1].source = home.path;
            cambiaPagina("HomePage");
        }
        /*          FINE FUNZIONI       */
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="PaginaPresentazione"/>
    <s:State name="HomePage"/>
    <s:State name="ListaTaskAnalysis"/>
    <s:State name="ScegliAzioneTaskAnalysis"/>
</s:states>
<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>


    <!-- =================================== MXML =================================== -->

    <!-- =================================== PaginaPresentazione =================================== -->
<s:Group id="gruppoPaginaPresentazione" includeIn="PaginaPresentazione" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:Button id="btnPresentazione" right="10" bottom="10" label="INIZIA"
              click="carica()"/>
</s:Group>
    <!-- =================================== HomePage =================================== -->
<s:Group id="gruppoHomePage" includeIn="HomePage,PaginaPresentazione" left="0" right="0" top="0"
         bottom="0" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">

    <s:Button id="btnVaiTaskAnalysis" includeIn="HomePage" width="600" height="90"
              label="TASK ANALYSIS" click="cambiaPagina('ListaTaskAnalysis')" fontSize="50"
              horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="80"/>
    <s:Button id="btnVaiStorieSociali" includeIn="HomePage" width="600" height="90"
              label="STORIE SOCIALI" fontSize="50" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="-80"/>

</s:Group>
    <!-- =================================== /HomePage =================================== -->

<s:Group id="gruppoListaTaskAnalysis" includeIn="ListaTaskAnalysis" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:Group id="gruppoBottoniListaTaskAnalyis" left="0" right="0" top="0" height="90"
             horizontalCenter="0">
        <s:Button id="btnExitListaTaskAnalysis" right="10" top="5" width="80" height="80"
                  icon="assets/exit.png"  click="chiudiApplicazione(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="btnHomeListaTaskAnalysis" right="100" top="5" width="80" height="80"
                  icon="assets/home.png" click = "cambiaPagina('HomePage')"/>
    </s:Group>
    <s:Image id="imgListaTaskAnalysis0" left="20" top="110" width="200" height="200"
             source="assets/cuboImmagini.png"/>
    <s:Image id="imgListaTaskAnalysis1" left="20" top="360" width="200" height="200"/>
    <s:Button id="btnSegreto1" left="10" bottom="10" width="90" height="90" alpha="0.1" click="combinazioneSegreta(1)"/>
    <s:Button id="btnSegreto2" right="10" bottom="10" width="90" height="90" alpha="0.1" click="combinazioneSegreta(2)"/>

</s:Group>
<s:Group id="gruppoListaTaskAnalysis0" includeIn="ScegliAzioneTaskAnalysis" left="0" right="0"
         top="0" bottom="0" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:Group id="gruppoBottoniListaTaskAnalyis0" left="0" right="0" top="0" height="90"
             horizontalCenter="0">
        <s:Button id="btnExitScegliAzioneTaskAnalysis0" right="10" top="5" width="80" height="80"
                  icon="assets/exit.png"  click="chiudiApplicazione(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="btnHomeScegliAzioneTaskAnalisys" right="100" top="5" width="80" height="80"
                  icon="assets/home.png" click = "cambiaPagina('HomePage')"/>
    </s:Group>

</s:Group>
    <!-- =================================== /HomePage =================================== -->
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to give them a source before the component instances are instantiated.  At what point in the Flex creation lifecycle does your for loop occur?  Are you receiving a specific error?

Comment: I don't receive error, only doesn't work.. The image are instantiated in static way, so aren't there instantiated before the creation complete?The loop occur in the handler of the creation complete of the state where there are the images..

Comment: Please "quantify" does not work?  If you're not receiving an error; what behavior are you expecting that you aren't getting?  Yes, components in MXML will be created before creationComplete executes.  Is your loop run in a creationComplete event handler?

Comment: Yes, it is in creationcomplete handler.my images should get the source, but they are invisible, so i think that don't get it..

Comment: Nothing in the code you provided makes the Images invisible.  Perhaps you need to share more code, including the structure of of your MXML Template.

Comment: I shared the interested part of my project.. Thank you for the help.. When I click on the "btnPresentazione" button to call "carica()" function, nothing happens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.. I put the images in the array when they are created:

```
<s:Image id="img" creationComplete = "loadImage(event,this.img,0) />
---------------------------------------------------------------------
public function loadImage(e:FlexEvent,img:Image,num:Number):void
{
  array[num] = img;
}
```

Thanks anyway..